# Weird styled icon visible on Iphone device only not Android

Tags: android, html, css, ios

I have almost dome my first own project. I have little issue with icon. Best way will be via images.

The first 2 images are from desktop Google Chrome but dimensioned as Iphone 12 Pro

[image]

3rd and 4th images are screenshots from my iPhone 13 Mini. As you can see in the 3rd and 4th pic is red cross visible and it should not be visible and also when I push hamburger menu red cross should be in the right top corner.

I must say I've never seen something like this. Usually, when I have an issue I use inspect element tool and in 90% I find a solution but I have no idea how to do it via iPhone. I tried a few apps but it's useless.. This is happening only on my iPhone device (Safari/Chrome). I've tried random Samsung All good.

[image]

**Sidebar**

```
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars vertical"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">
    <div class="close-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times vertical"></i>
    </div>
```

**Sidebar.css**

I have a lot of css lines inside but the 2 important are:

```
.close-btn {
      position: absolute;
      color: red;
    
      font-size: 30px;
      right: 0px;
      margin: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .menu-btn {
      color: #fff;
      position: fixed;
      font-size: 35px;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 7px;
      left: 14px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to debug using the iPhone Web Inspector, you will need to connect your iPhone to a Mac via a USB cable.

Here you can read the how to:

https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798

Comment: Yah i find this solution. The issue is i dont have Mac :/ And didnt find any windows solution :(

Comment: Another option is to get a free trial at [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/users/sign_up?ref=guide-how-to-debug-on-iphone-safari-mid&product=live)